# Connect Multiple Journey to a Single Automation in a batch process

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I'd like to know if it is possible to connect more than one journey within a single automation. The Automation studio receives a large amount of data on a regular basis and sends it to different journeys. What is the correct way of doing this.

My attempt:
Within the automation studio, I have created a scheduler which inserts records to a SQL table (Data Extension). Have created a server side script to read data from the tables and then fire multiple journeys. However, such a solution is slow as the java script becomes a bottleneck as the SQL operations are relatively faster.

PS: Looking for something that is faster and can be scaled to handle data in batches.

Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Data extension as an entry source for your journeys. From automation studio, you are pushing records to multiple data extensions. You can use these data extension as an entry source for your respective journey. So when ever the records is getting pushed to data extension your journey will get triggered.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. Pushing data to a DE will not trigger a journey. An automation needs a journey trigger event (normally present in the last automation step).